# Using findContour and the resulting contours to approximate line segments to find line intersection

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to write a program to handle the finding the intersections of the lines outlining a rectangular object, (eg. Computer screen). I attempted to use hough lines originally, however, due to variable lighting conditions as well as content appearing on the screen, the lines that are drawn are not always the outline of the screen. Additionally, there may be a large amount of other random objects in the frame.

My next approach was to use contours which always seem to outline both the screen as well as being able to handle the variable content encapsulated within it. How do I go about using the contours to approximate a line?

I used

```
print len(contours)
```

and received a contour fairly long contour length > 200 consistently.

Feel free to comment asking for clarity.

**EDIT**
[image: Example]
The green "lines" are the contours found by findContours. I am primarily interested in the contour surrounding the screen content. How can I use those contours to find a line approximating those contours and then find the point of intersection of the two lines? This is from a webcam stream so conditions, angle, and distance may not stay constant.

Comment: can you add/link images?

Answer (score 1):

A first step might be to use the size of the contours to filter out those you are not interested in since the smaller contours usually correspond to stuff on the screen.

Also, the findContour method can be used to return the contours in a hierarchy of nested contours. This will tell you which contour is contained within another and allow you to get the outer-most, second outer-most one etc. If you are trying to get the screen, then it would have to be a large contour that is possibly the second largest and nested just below the contour for the monitor.

After obtaining the potential contours, which are just list of points, you can do a robust fitting for a single rectangle using just these points either by RANSAC (with a model for rectangles, not homography), or hough transform modified for this case.